# Is this group representation faithful?

Tags: group-theory, gap

I am interested in the following group. (It's the fundamental group of the figure eight knot with the added requirement that $a$ and $b$ have order 3.)

$G=\left\langle a,b\ |\ a^3=1,b^3=1,aba^{-1}ba=bab^{-1}ab\right\rangle$

Using GAP I noticed many quotients of this group had order $12n^3$ for various integers $n$, which made me wonder if the group was isomorphic to something like $\mathbb{Z}^3\rtimes A_4$. This led me to find the following $4\times4$ matricies which actually do satisfy the above relations.

$a\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$b\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\2 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Is this a faithful representation? How do I prove this either way?

Comment: This is most likely a very hard problem - I would suggest posting it on MathOverflow...

Comment: By the way, did you just add the order three requirement to see what happened, or was there a deep meaning to this?

Comment: Just to see what would happen. I know if you add the order three (or four or five) requirement to the fundamental group of the trefoil you get a finite group. I'm really just a math hobbyist toying around.

Comment: Well, it was an interesting thing to do. How did you find the matrices?

Comment: Based on my guess, I pictured an infinite cubic lattice, with its rotations and translations, so I looked for affine transformations. The lower right 3x3 parts of the matricies are just rotations of a third of a turn, along a different axis for $a$ and $b$. Then just some algebra and picking integers to force the complicated relation to hold while keeping them order 3.

Comment: That's a nice idea! You already have a paper there, if you write down a little about how you did it. The faithfulness question is very interesting, but, as I say likely to be quite hard - there is a bunch of related work by Long and Reid (which you can look up on arXiv. I sent them a pointer to this question, they might have more concrete things to say...

Comment: Can (should?) one write a paper if one is not in academia? I'm simply curious about math. I do appreciate you looking at this question, and sending it to other knowledgeable people is already more than I had hoped for.

Comment: One can and should, since the result is interesting (and not being in academia is only relevant in getting (or not) promotions based on your work). I find that writing things up clarifies my own thinking on the subject, and getting other people to look at the work is important for those of us who just want to know the answer (or at least different avenues of attack).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that the group is isomorphic to an extension of ${\mathbb Z}^3$ by $A_4$, but it is a nonsplit extension, and not a semidirect product. Your representation must be faithful, because no proper quotient of $G$ is isomorphic to itself (i.e. it is a Hopfian group).

I have to disagree with Igor Rivin about this being a hard problem. It is a straightforward computer calculation. Since the kernel $K$ of the homomorphism onto $A_4$ has finite index in $G$, you can use the Reidemeister-Schreier algorithm to compute a presentation of $K$, from which you can see immediately that $K \cong {\mathbb Z}^3$.

I found, that the finite quotient group of order $96$ that is an extension of $C_2^3$ by $A_4$ is a nonsplit extension, and so $G$ must itself be nonsplit.

You could certainly do this in GAP, and I could figure out how to do it, but maybe someone else will do that first! I am slightly more familiar with Magma, so I will give the Magma commands below. It is the Rewrite command that runs the Reidemeister-Schreier algorithm. The three relations are commutators - for some reason Magma writes the commutator [x,y] as (x,y).

```
> G:=Group<a,b|a^3=1, b^3=1, a*b*a^-1*b*a=b*a*b^-1*a*b >;
> h:=Homomorphisms(G,Alt(4))
> K:=Kernel(h[1]);
> K:=Rewrite(G,K);
> K;
Finitely presented group K on 3 generators
Generators as words in group G
    K.1 = (G.2^-1 * G.1)^2
    K.2 = G.2 * G.1 * G.2 * G.1^-1 * G.2^-1 * G.1^-1
    K.3 = G.1^-1 * G.2^-1 * G.1 * G.2^-1 * G.1^-1
Relations
   (K.2^-1, K.3) = Id(K)
   (K.2^-1, K.1^-1) = Id(K)
   (K.3, K.1^-1) = Id(K)
```

Here is the same calculation done in GAP:

```
gap> F := FreeGroup(2);; a:=F.1;; b:=F.2;;
gap> rels := [a^3, b^3, a*b*a^-1*b*a/(b*a*b^-1*a*b)];;
gap> G := F/rels;;
gap> homs := GQuotients(G, AlternatingGroup(4));;
gap> K := Kernel(homs[1]);;
gap> P := PresentationSubgroup(G,K);;
gap> TzGo(P);;
#I  there are 3 generators and 3 relators of total length 12
gap> TzPrintPresentation(P);
#I  generators:
#I  1.  _x1   4 occurrences
#I  2.  _x2   4 occurrences
#I  3.  _x3   4 occurrences
#I  relators:
#I  1. _x2^-1*_x1^-1*_x2*_x1
#I  2. _x3*_x2*_x3^-1*_x2^-1
#I  3. _x3*_x1*_x3^-1*_x1^-1
#I  there are 3 generators and 3 relators of total length 12
```

Comment: Derek, the fact that you can do it doesn't mean it's easy!

Comment: I said it was straightforward rather than easy.  It is a routine application of a well-known algorithm.

Comment: Yes, all true. but I think the whole package (discovering the representation and the group structure) is quite nice.

Comment: Thanks for including the GAP code. I'm working on finding slightly nicer matrices to really emphasize the group structure and writing all this up. Where is a good place to post my writeup?

Comment: In order to show this is a semidirect product, don't we also need to show that there is a subgroup of $G$ that is isomorphic to $A_4$?

Comment: Good point! In fact it isn't a semidirect product, it's a nonsplit extension, and there are no elements of order $2$. I have edited my answer.